# How to run a Macro in Excel only in a certain column?

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

This macro for excel automatically links all checkboxes in my active worksheet to the cell they are in. However I need it to run only in a certain column and not the whole worksheet. The code looks as follows:

```
Sub LinkChecklist()

Dim chk As CheckBox

For Each chk In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
    chk.LinkedCell = chk.TopLeftCell.Offset(0, 0).Address
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the column property of the `.TopLeftCell` range?
In the below example it will only fire if the `TopLeftCell` is in the `D` column?

BTW, the `.Offset(0,0)` is superfluous? It doesn't add or do anything?

```
Sub LinkChecklist()
Dim chk As CheckBox

For Each chk In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
    col = chk.TopLeftCell.Column
    If col = 4 Then
        chk.LinkedCell = chk.TopLeftCell.Address
    End If
Next
End sub
```

As a suggestion, learn to use the `Locals` window and a breakpoint in your code to inspect the value of your variables. That way you can very often discover valuable properties that you can use?

Comment: I have no idea how to code hence why I left the offset part of the old code in. I now know that it was useless I just didnt want to break anything. With that being said i tried your code but unfortunately it doesnt work. It gives me a "Invalid outside procedure" error. Since I cant use images in post I can only link it from imgur: https://imgur.com/a/slei6js Thats an example of the chart I am using. I want to only run the macro on colum D without changing any of the other checkboxes
I only changed the column from your code to 4 as D is the 4th column.

Comment: did you include the `Sub LinkChecklist()` and the `end sub` at respectively the beginning and the end? I only updated the inner text of the function? I have now also updated the code section in the answer to reflect the whole `sub` statement and your column is column D => meaning `if col=4...` should be used

Comment: @Kazoko can you provide a download link from Dropbox or WeTransfer?

Comment: I actually did forget to add `end sub` because I thought `End If` was already the end of the whole code but I think its only the end of the "if" condition for it to run. I used the updated code of yours and now it runs like a charm. Thanks a lot :D

Comment: @Kazoko If it has answered your question then tick this answer as 'the answer'. That way it will close the question and we keep SO clean?

Comment: Alright I marked it as the answer thanks.